# Construction of a surjective (or onto) function relating $X$ and $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $c>1$ be a fixed positive real number and let $X=(0,1)$. Let $h(t):(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a real function.

We have the following result:

**Lemma**: For any $y$ in the set $Y=(1,c]$, there exist $x_{0}=x_{0}(y)\in X=(0,1)$ such that the function $h(t)$ is non-increasing for $0<t<x_{0}$.

I want to construct a surjective (or onto) function relating $X$ and $Y$ by using the **Lemma** and relating $x_{0}$ to $y$.

Comment: I am happy to come up with a different answer, but I am still not clear on why the lemma requires some fixed $y$. The only thing the lemma states is that there exists an $x_{0}\in (0,1)$ such that $h(t)$ is non-increasing on $(0,x_{0})$. Can you perhaps give a bit more context what you want to use the function for?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens: This is a part of a problem of chaotic discrete dynamics.

Comment: So what do you actually want? Do you want a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f$ is surjective, $f(x_{0})=y$. And $h$ is somehow used in the construction of $f$. If so why need $h$ be part of the construction of $f$, because you don't need it for the construction of $f$, hence any answer I come up with most likely won't be what your looking for. (Side question is $h$ continuous?)

Comment: @FlorisClaassens: $h$ is not continuous. $f$ need not to be continuous just surjective. It is good to use $h$ in the construction.

Comment: Is it required to use $h$ in the construction?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens: No, but it is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f:X\rightarrow Y$ given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1+\frac{y-1}{x_{0}}x&\text{ if }x\in(0,x_{0}].\\1+\frac{2c-2y}{1-x_{0}}x&\text{ if }x\in(x_{0},\frac{1+x_{0}}{2}].\\c-\frac{2c}{1-x_{0}}(x-\frac{1+x_{0}}{2})&\text{ if }x\in(\frac{1+x_{0}}{2},1).\end{cases}$$
Note that $f$ is surjective, continuous and $f(x_{0})=y$. Furthermore note that $h$ could be a constant function and therefore in general there is no natural way to construct a surjective function from $X$ to $Y$ using $h$.